# Eclipse /bin/sh: g++: command not found

Tags: c++, eclipse

I had to upgrade my gcc version to utilize the new C++11 standards. After following the instructions at http://ask.xmodulo.com/upgrade-gcc-centos.html . I started getting the error "/bin/sh: g++: command not found" when I try to build my project. How can I fix this? It looks like gcc installed fine by looking at the below output.

gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5)

Comment: and did you try`g++ --version`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

G++ appears to be not installed. Find how to install `gcc` in your OS. After this, you have to make Eclipse find `g++`. I recommend to you, to install CDT plugins. They have many ready tools for C/C++ programming and it is fully compatible with gcc toolset.

Comment: g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5)  It appears G++ is installed, how do I change Eclipse to find it?

Comment: @RGibson1972 Did you already installed EClipse with CDT? If so, take a look at the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_build_toolchain.htm).

Comment: Yes Eclipse w/ CDT was already instaleld and working fine before I upgraded GCC.

Comment: Just to avoid any kind of Eclipse´s misconfiguration cause by your update, can your try to create another C++ "Hello World" project? Just to be fine that is a general problem and not specific of your project env.

Comment: export CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/gcc  
export CPP=/opt/rh/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/cpp
export CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/c++   I tried using that but it appears it is not correctly setting those paths how do I fix this?